# Magento 2 : Call Helper Without Using __construct in Own Module

Tags: magento2, helper

I have created a new module and override the

> \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description

function using preference.
In this module we create new helper located in

> Custom_Hello/Helper/Data.php

Then how to call this helper in

> Custom_Hello/Block/Product/View/Description.php

If we use __construct got some error.

```
public function __construct(\Custom\Hello\Helper\Data $helper)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
    }
```

Anyone helpme

Comment: you can use object manager method into this case, As I know that is not peoper method.

Comment: I'm new in magento. But using plugin we got solution then using this way error

Comment: Could you provide the error you are receiving? The way you are injecting it is the proper approach so if we can resolve the error that would be best.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:652 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() #1

Answer (score 4):

You can add your custom helper in constructor, but as this method is present in the class you're extending then you'd pass the right parameters in it, not just your helper

```
class Description extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
```

You are extending **\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description** so let's see constructor in this class (in 2.3 version, you can check this in your project for other version, if that's the case)

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

So, in your class you'd pass that **$context** & **$registry** parameters. You can do that this way

```
public function __construct(
    \Custom\Hello\Helper\Data $helper,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->helper = $helper;
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. Already got the solution and again thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution. If we use following way

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Custom\Hello\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data);
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    }
```

Comment: Answered at same time :)

Answer (score 0):

**In `Custom_Hello/Block/Product/View/Description.php` File**

```
protected $helper;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
        \Custom\Hello\Helper\Data $helper
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->helper= $heper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

**And You Can Call Your Helper Function Like this**

```
$this->helper->yourFunctionName()
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can use directly without contructor

```
$this->helper('CompanyName\ModuleName\Helper\Data')->yourfunctionname();
```

Comment: We tried this way not working.

Comment: This is valid for templates, but not for classes